# What to do with two gold on one card?

Tags: jamaica

If a card has gold on both morning and evening action, do you have to put them in separate holds or can you combine them into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The morning action and evening action are done consecutively. The case of the card you're describing is discussed in the Continent section of [the rules](http://www.gameworks.ch/2010/pdf/jamaica_rules.pdf) at the very bottom:

> doubloons obtained with the gold-gold card cannot be combined and placed in a single hold